# Putting a timeline for dates in moderncv

Tags: tikz-pgf, moderncv, gradient, moderntimeline

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`moderntimeline`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderntimeline)

I just had the idea of using a timeline to specify dates in my CV. I've made a mockup in Inkscape:

[image: mockup]

The idea, as you see it, is to display the dates of experience on timelines instead of just typesetting them. I think this makes it nicer and more understandable somehow. When the position is still held, I want to use a gradient at the end of the line. Since I'm using `moderncv` and it uses lines for sections (like the orange line in front of "Experience"), I would like to calibrate the time lines on this line, setting a start and an end dates corresponding to the extremities of the section line. In my example, the section line goes from 2000 to 2011 for example.

I think using TiKz could do. How would you suggest to implement this? Is there an existing package that would almost do this?

Comment: it will be nice if the package come up with a template that includes an entry of each nice stuff that the package can do.

Comment: @SAM if you want an example, you can check my own CV on https://github.com/raphink/CV

Comment: @ℝaphink: The code in my answer doesn't work with recent versions of moderncv. Could you accept your answer instead of mine, so mine isn't shown at the top?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

For the record, I have adapted Jake's code and began working on a new package called [moderntimeline](https://github.com/raphink/moderntimeline):

```
\usepackage{moderntimeline}

% Set the scale.
% I go up to 2013 otherwise some late dates overflow on the entry
\tlmaxdates{1999}{2013}
% Set the line width.
% This automatically sets the space under the top label to be 1pt more
\tlwidth{0.8ex}
% Set the labels text size
\tltext{\tiny}
```

And then a few examples:

```
\section{Experience}
\subsection{IT Experience}
\tlcventry[blue]{2006}{0}{Systems Engineer}{\href{http://www.orness.com}{ORNESS} then \href{http://www.alten.fr}{Alten}}{Sophia Antipolis}{}
{Consultant at France T\'el\'ecom
\begin{itemize}
 \item Administration of Cfengine, FAI and the software package repository;
 \item Renewal and industrialization of the software deployment system for Debian/Ubuntu;
 \item Management of the Gforge (collaborative development web interface) platform;
 \item Monitoring of the fleet of servers;
 \item Writing of technical documentation.
\end{itemize}}
```

[image: tl1]

```
\tllabelcventry[purple]{1999}{2000}{1999--2000}{Paramedic}
  {\href{http://www.croix-rouge.fr/}{French Red Cross}}{Paris Suburbs}{}
  {Served in several volunteer missions as a paramedic}
```

[image: tl2]

```
\tldatelabelcventry[red]{2004}{July 2004}{Blue Collar Internship}
  {\href{http://www.snecma.com}{SNECMA}}{Moissy-Cramayel}{}
  {Assembled and equilibrated turbo reactors for planes}
```

[image: tl3]

```
\tldatecventry[green]{2005}{Student in Pedagogy (`Gestion Mentale')}
  {\href{http://www.ifgm.org/}{IFGM}}{Bordeaux}{}
  {Pedagogy, Didacticism, Cognitive Psychology}
```

[image: tl4]

**Edit:** Since `moderncv` aligns the left column to the right, there were weird things with dates, so I decided to put a white rectangle all over each entry to make sure the whole space was used. After that, my wife suggested I used a thin line to every entry to make things clearer, so now it looks like this (color and width of the thin line can be set):

[image: tl5]

Full examples can be seen [in my updated CV](http://cv.raphink.info).

Comment: Appreciate you turning useful thing into packages!

Comment: Package uploaded to CTAN :-)

Comment: @NN: If I had some time, I think I would turn a lot of answers on TeX.SX into packages. I just think it makes life easier once it's done.

Comment: I really like the version with the thin lines - makes the entire timeline thought clearer to the reader. Thank your wife from me! =)

Comment: I am trying to use this package with beamer. I am preparing the slides of my PhD and I would like to use this package for a slide with all my publications and research stays. It should be feasible, wouldn't it? So far I got some errors but I guess they are at my end.

Comment: tex community is great http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99236/moderntimeline-in-beamer-latex that seems like a good starting point.

Answer (score 71):

**This code doesn't work with versions of moderncv after 2012. Please use ℝaphink's [moderntimeline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29783/2552) package instead**

Here's a way of getting this to work with `moderncv`. I've defined a new macro, `\funkycventry` that takes the start and end year and then all the same arguments as `cventry`, and uses this to draw the timeline bar in the same colour and width as the section headers. If the end year is `0`, the bar fades out, and no end year is printed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{moderncv}
\usepackage{tikz}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}

\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tikzset{
    startyear/.style={
        font=\scriptsize,
        name=startyear,
        above=3pt,
        inner xsep=0pt,
        anchor=base west,
    },
    endyear/.style={
        font=\scriptsize,
        name=endyear,
        below,
        inner xsep=0pt,
        anchor=north east,
    }
}

\def\firstyear{2000}
\def\lastyear{2011}
\pgfmathsetmacro\yearrange{\lastyear-\firstyear}

\newcommand{\funkycventry}[7]{%
\pgfmathsetmacro\endyear{ifthenelse(#2==0,\lastyear,#2)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\startfraction{(#1-\firstyear)/(\lastyear-\firstyear)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\endfraction{(\endyear-\firstyear)/(\lastyear-\firstyear)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\ongoing{!(#2==0)}
 \cventry{\tikz[baseline=(endyear.north)]{
    \fill [sectionrectanglecolor] (0,0) 
        ++(\startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0pt)
        node [startyear] {#1}
        rectangle (\endfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0.5ex)
        node [endyear] {\pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(#2==0,,#2)}\pgfmathresult}
        (\hintscolumnwidth,0pt) ;
    \ifnum #2=0
        \shade [left color=sectionrectanglecolor]
        (\endfraction*\hintscolumnwidth-1em,0pt) rectangle ++(1em,0.5ex);
    \fi}
}
{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}
}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\funkycventry{2002}{2007}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\funkycventry{2000}{2011}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\funkycventry{2005}{0}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Great. I've adapted the code for my need. I might make a package out of it.

Comment: Looking forward to seeing it!

Comment: I have pushed a (not ready for release yet, missing the doc) version [on github](https://github.com/raphink/moderntimeline).

Comment: This was beautiful. I'm going to start working on my CV right now!

Comment: @Jake it is very nice but somehow it doesnt compile for me using pdflatex i get this error 4 times: `! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/sectionrectanglecolor' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.` maybe should be updated or replaced with a [moderntimeline](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderntimeline) example.

Comment: @Jake your [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54757/92620) contain a syntax error i believe, `\tllabelcventry{2006.834}{2009.67}` should be integers instead so it compile correctly.

Comment: @SAM: `moderncv` was refactored a couple of years ago to use different color names, so this answer doesn't work anymore. I'll add a note. The [other answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54757/92620) still works fine, for me, though, even with the float values instead of integers.

Comment: @Jake `moderntimeline` now supports months in a simpler way. Recently I made some changes to the code on my CV to display them with three letters; when I'll have some time I'll make a pull request to modertimeline repository.

Answer (score 4):

If I understood your description correctly, this could be what you need:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick]
\def\timelineunfinished#1#2{\node (refnode) at (0,0) {};%
                   \shade [left color=#1,right color=white] (${#2-2000}*(1,0)$) rectangle ++(${2011-#2}*(1,0)+1*(0,-0.5)$) node [pos=0, label=#2] (startdate) {};}

\timelineunfinished{red}{2005}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\timelinefinished#1#2#3{\node (refnode) at (0,0) {};%
                   \path [fill=#1] (${#2-2000}*(1,0)$) rectangle ++(${#3-#2}*(1,0)+1*(0,-0.5)$) node [pos=0, label=#2] (startdate) {} node [label=#3] (enddate) at ++(0,0.5) {};}

\timelinefinished{red}{2003}{2007}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I did, is define two new commands, one for timelines that have a start and an end date (these will not be rendered with gradient, but with solid fill) and one for the timelines that are 'in progress'. The timelines can start at 2000 earliest and end at latest in 2011. To change the limits, just replace the numbers in the code accordingly.

The code can probably be cleaned up, error checking could be included to avoid having the end earlier than the start, etc. But for a primer I hope this will do.