# "References" section in a CV

Tags: resume, cv

By "References", I mean the recommendation letter writers, 
For example, the VERY bottom of this CV, 
http://pages.uoregon.edu/bwebster/NSA-CV.pdf
with 4 people.

Can someone point to a CV template with this "references" section? Or maybe what functions should I use to make such effect? (with 2 people on parallel blocks)
I find plenty of CV templates online, but none of them has this part.

Comment: I don't use any specific CV template, but you can achieve this effect easily with a simple `tabular` environment, or the `multicols` package.

Comment: I use [moderncv.](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) If you navigate to this page you will see a link for examples. Moderncv allows for various types of typeset formatting. You may view my choice of including references [here](http://www.math.uakron.edu/~tprice/vitae/vitae.pdf). Recently, there was a [post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29725/putting-a-timeline-for-dates-in-moderncv) on this forum for adding a timeline to the dates. You might do a search in this forum for other comments about moderncv.

Comment: As I assume the CV you're linking to is your own, I suggest you insert the relevant part of it in your question as a picture, so users can see immediately what you are/were looking for.

Comment: The link is now broken.

Answer (score 50):

Using bits and pieces from `moderncv.cls`, I put together and new entry type `\cvdoublecolumn` and a macro `\cvreference`. They will allow you to typeset your references like in your example, using the CV document class [`moderncv`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/).
If you're not familiar with `moderncv`, there's a [big example file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template.tex) showing a lot of possibilities.

**Astrinus's edit**: I've substituted `\cvline` with `\cvitem`, as stated below, to ease copy and paste.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

% Define \cvdoublecolumn, which sets its arguments in two columns without any labels

\newcommand{\cvdoublecolumn}[2]{%
  \cvitem[0.75em]{}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemcolumnwidth}#1\end{minipage}%
    \hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemcolumnwidth}#2\end{minipage}%
    }%
}

% usage: \cvreference{name}{address line 1}{address line 2}{address line 3}{address line 4}{e-mail address}{phone number}
% Everything but the name is optional
% If \addresssymbol, \emailsymbol or \phonesymbol are specified, they will be used.
% (Per default, \addresssymbol isn't specified, the other two are specified.)
% If you don't like the symbols, remove them from the following code, including the tilde ~ (space).

\newcommand{\cvreference}[7]{%
    \textbf{#1}\newline% Name
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\addresssymbol~#2\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{#3\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{#4\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{#5\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{\emailsymbol~\texttt{#6}\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}{}{\phonesymbol~#7}}

\begin{document} 
\maketitle

\section{References}

\subsection{set in separate rows}

\cvdoublecolumn{\cvreference{Nicolai Reshetikhin}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {University of California}
    {Berkeley, CA 94720-3840}
    {}
    {reshetik@math.berkeley.edu}
    {510-643-6234}%
    }
    {\cvreference{Mikhail Khovanov}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {Columbia University}
    {990 Broadway}
    {New York, NY 10027}
    {khovanov@columbia.edu}
    {212-854-4186}%
    }

\cvdoublecolumn{\cvreference{Roman Bezrukavnikov}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {Massachusetts Institute of Technology}
    {77 Massachusetts Avenue}
    {Cambridge, MA 02139}
    {bezrukav@math.mit.edu}
    {617-253-2684}
    }
    {\cvreference{Tom Braden}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {University of Massachusetts}
    {Amherst, MA 94720-3840}
    {}
    {braden@math.umass.edu}
    {413-545-1732}
    }

\subsection{set in one row only (like your example)}

\cvdoublecolumn{\cvreference{Nicolai Reshetikhin}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {University of California}
    {Berkeley, CA 94720-3840}
    {}
    {reshetik@math.berkeley.edu}
    {510-643-6234}\\[1em]
    \cvreference{Roman Bezrukavnikov}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {Massachusetts Institute of Technology}
    {77 Massachusetts Avenue}
    {Cambridge, MA 02139}
    {bezrukav@math.mit.edu}
    {617-253-2684}
    }
    {\cvreference{Mikhail Khovanov}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {Columbia University}
    {990 Broadway}
    {New York, NY 10027}
    {khovanov@columbia.edu}
    {212-854-4186}\\[1em]
    \cvreference{Tom Braden}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {University of Massachusetts}
    {Amherst, MA 94720-3840}
    {}
    {braden@math.umass.edu}
    {413-545-1732}
    }

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of the output]

Comment: This won't work unless `\cvline` is replaced by `\cvitem`. `\cvline` is no longer defined in `moderncv.cls`.

Comment: Great stuff! Thanks for sharing. If you also want to make the emails clickable, and add another entry for mobile phone numbers, use this:

`\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{\emailsymbol~\texttt{\href{mailto:#6}{\nolinkurl{#6}}}\newline}
\ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}{}{\phonesymbol~#7\newline}
\ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{}}{}{\mobilephonesymbol~#8}}`

..and change the number behind `\cvreference` from 7 to 8.

Comment: In order to get the example output, I needed to add the line `\moderncvtheme{casual}` in the preamble.

Comment: If I use `\cvdoublecolumn` I receive and error

Answer (score 24):

I recommend a mixture of `minipage`s and `tabular`. For example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{marvosym} % For cool symbols.
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lr}
% Referee 1
\begin{minipage}[t]{2.5in}
Prof.\ X Y\\
Place A\\
Location B\\
Country and Postcode\\
\Telefon\ +00 1 234 5678\\
\Letter\ \href{mailto:X@A.ac.jp}{X\textrm{@}A.ac.jp}
\end{minipage}
&
% Referee 2
\begin{minipage}[t]{2.5in}
Prof.\ X Y\\
Place A\\
Location B\\
Country and Postcode\\
\Telefon\ +00 1 234 5678\\
\Letter\ \href{mailto:X@A.ac.jp}{X\textrm{@}A.ac.jp}
\end{minipage}
\\
\\ % Additional newline for spacing.
% Referee 3
\begin{minipage}[t]{2.5in}
Prof.\ X Y\\
Place A\\
Location B\\
Country and Postcode\\
\Telefon\ +00 1 234 5678\\
\Letter\ \href{mailto:X@A.ac.jp}{X\textrm{@}A.ac.jp}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Each referee lives in a `minipage`, and these are arranged in a `tabular` environment.

Comment: @mark-s-everitt This was an accident: I used a cell phone, and missed the keys.  To the poster: sorry, but I corrected the mistake as soon as I saw it.  Please see also    http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1985/is-locking-downvotes-the-good-feature

Comment: Ah, ok. I thought someone had a problem with the answer.

Comment: I'm voting this up, if only because I couldn't even compile the other answer.