# displaying 3 references in resume on the same line

Tags: tables, multicol, resume

I am using the following template (from ["References" section in a CV](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34881/references-section-in-a-cv)). The problem is that I only have 3 references so I would like to place them harmoniously into a single line. I was thinking about using multicols (that automatically sets the correct column width) but I do not know hox to proceed.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{marvosym} % For cool symbols.
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lr}
% Referee 1
\begin{minipage}[t]{2.5in}
Prof.\ X Y\\
Place A\\
Location B\\
Country and Postcode\\
\Telefon\ +00 1 234 5678\\
\Letter\ \href{mailto:X@A.ac.jp}{X\textrm{@}A.ac.jp}
\end{minipage}
&
% Referee 2
\begin{minipage}[t]{2.5in}
Prof.\ X Y\\
Place A\\
Location B\\
Country and Postcode\\
\Telefon\ +00 1 234 5678\\
\Letter\ \href{mailto:X@A.ac.jp}{X\textrm{@}A.ac.jp}
\end{minipage}
\\
\\ % Additional newline for spacing.
% Referee 3
\begin{minipage}[t]{2.5in}
Prof.\ X Y\\
Place A\\
Location B\\
Country and Postcode\\
\Telefon\ +00 1 234 5678\\
\Letter\ \href{mailto:X@A.ac.jp}{X\textrm{@}A.ac.jp}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Right now your question is independendent of your intention to create resumés. Please edit your question to represent only to problem of typesetting multiple columns or clarify your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you might not need the `tabular` environment in your code.

I will supply three solutions for you, which are only different in how they handle pagebreaks:

- `minipage`: they won't be broken over pages
- `paracol`: they will be broken independently and stay in their column
- `multicols`: they will be broken into the next column (from left to right)

Here's an MWE with all of them and your sample code.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[a5paper, landscape]{geometry} % demo only
\usepackage{lipsum} % demo only

\usepackage{marvosym} % For cool symbols.
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2-4]

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\textwidth}

    Prof.\ X Y\\
    Place A\\
    Location B\\
    Country and Postcode\\
    \Telefon\ +00 1 234 5678\\
    \Letter\ \href{mailto:X@A.ac.jp}{X\textrm{@}A.ac.jp}

\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\textwidth}

    Prof.\ X Y\\
    Place A\\
    Location B\\
    Country and Postcode\\
    \Telefon\ +00 1 234 5678\\
    \Letter\ \href{mailto:X@A.ac.jp}{X\textrm{@}A.ac.jp}

\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\textwidth}

    Prof.\ X Y\\
    Place A\\
    Location B\\
    Country and Postcode\\
    \Telefon\ +00 1 234 5678\\
    \Letter\ \href{mailto:X@A.ac.jp}{X\textrm{@}A.ac.jp}

\end{minipage}

\lipsum[5-6]

\begin{paracol}{3}

    Prof.\ X Y\\
    Place A\\
    Location B\\
    Country and Postcode\\
    \Telefon\ +00 1 234 5678\\
    \Letter\ \href{mailto:X@A.ac.jp}{X\textrm{@}A.ac.jp}

\switchcolumn

    Prof.\ X Y\\
    Place A\\
    Location B\\
    Country and Postcode\\
    \Telefon\ +00 1 234 5678\\
    \Letter\ \href{mailto:X@A.ac.jp}{X\textrm{@}A.ac.jp}

\switchcolumn

    Prof.\ X Y\\
    Place A\\
    Location B\\
    Country and Postcode\\
    \Telefon\ +00 1 234 5678\\
    \Letter\ \href{mailto:X@A.ac.jp}{X\textrm{@}A.ac.jp}

\end{paracol}

\lipsum[8-9]

\begin{multicols}{3}

    Prof.\ X Y\\
    Place A\\
    Location B\\
    Country and Postcode\\
    \Telefon\ +00 1 234 5678\\
    \Letter\ \href{mailto:X@A.ac.jp}{X\textrm{@}A.ac.jp}

\vfill\columnbreak

    Prof.\ X Y\\
    Place A\\
    Location B\\
    Country and Postcode\\
    \Telefon\ +00 1 234 5678\\
    \Letter\ \href{mailto:X@A.ac.jp}{X\textrm{@}A.ac.jp}

\vfill\columnbreak

    Prof.\ X Y\\
    Place A\\
    Location B\\
    Country and Postcode\\
    \Telefon\ +00 1 234 5678\\
    \Letter\ \href{mailto:X@A.ac.jp}{X\textrm{@}A.ac.jp}

\end{multicols}

\lipsum[10]

\end{document}
```

PS: You should not use `\\` for vertical spacing: use `\vskip` or `\vspace` instead.

Comment: @Noobie if this is an answer for you please don't forget to edit your question and remove the references of resumé and change the question to be focused on typesetting multiple columns. It will help others to find it.