# cvdoublecolumn producing an error while making references using the package modern CV in latex

Tags: moderncv

I am making my CV using the TeX package `moderncv`. I wish to enter references in my CV. I am getting an error when I use the command for double column. The error is

> undefined control sequence \listdoublecolumnwidth

Following is my code. Many thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}   
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage{hyperref}                               
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}
\firstname{Ridhima}
\familyname{Gupta}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\newcommand{\cvdoublecolumn}[2]{%
 \cvitem[0.75em]{}{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemcolumnwidth}#1\end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemcolumnwidth}#2\end{minipage}%
    }%
    }

    \newcommand{\cvreference}[7]{%
    \textbf{#1}\newline% Name
\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\addresssymbol~#2\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{#3\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{#4\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{#5\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{\emailsymbol~\texttt{#6}\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}{}{\phonesymbol~#7}}

 \cvdoublecolumn{\cvreference{E. Somanathan}
{Professor}
{Economics and Planning Unit}
{Indian Statistical Institute}
{Delhi-110016}
 {som@isid.ac.in}
{+91-11-41493939}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you have several errors in your code.

You defined two commands with different number of parameters:

```
\cvdoublecolumn{col1}{col2}
\cvreference{name}{addr1}{addr2}{addr3}{addr4}{email}{phone}
```

Then you have to use them as follows in your code (please see that I moved the definitions **before** line `\begin{document}`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}   

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\cvdoublecolumn}[2]{%
  \cvitem[0.75em]{}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemcolumnwidth}#1\end{minipage}%
    \hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemcolumnwidth}#2\end{minipage}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\cvreference}[7]{%
  \textbf{#1}\newline% Name
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\addresssymbol~#2\newline}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{#3\newline}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{#4\newline}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{#5\newline}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{\emailsymbol~\texttt{#6}\newline}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}{}{\phonesymbol~#7}%
}


\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
%\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}

\firstname{Ridhima}
\familyname{Gupta}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\cvreference{name}{addr1}{addr2}{addr3}{addr4}{email}{phone}

\cvdoublecolumn{% 
  \cvreference{E. Somanathan}%
    {Professor}%
    {Economics and Planning Unit}%
    {Indian Statistical Institute}%
    {Delhi-110016}%
    {som@isid.ac.in}%
    {+91-11-41493939}%
}{\cvreference{name}{addr1}{addr2}{addr3}{addr4}{email}{phone}}

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

Comment: I copy pasted just your commands and ran them in a new tex file, I get an error saying ./Untitled-2.tex:49: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \listdoubleitemcolumnwidth 
                                      
l.49 ...addr1}{addr2}{addr3}{addr4}{email}{phone}}
                                                  
? I also don't want my output to look like this. I don't want fields like name, addr1 etc. to appear. It should look like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34881/references-section-in-a-cv

Comment: sadly no, Just got busy with other stuff. Will let you know as soon as I do. Thanks for getting in touch!

Comment: @Ridhima Do you have any news for us?

Comment: I made a new CV with a new style file. But thanks so much for asking me :-) honestly it was so long ago that I don't recall what I tried and what worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your `moderncv.cls` (and perhaps some other `.sty` files) must be out of date. Update it (them), from https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv.