# Horizontal spacing commands only work for first item in list with multicol

Tags: moderncv

I'm trying to make my resume shorter by adding a multicolumn environment `multicol`.  I'm using the class `moderncv` and package `multicol` to lay out a list of items in a special two column section (in the middle of my otherwise one-column resume).  It works fine, except that the whole thing is shifted too far to the left, so I'm trying to hack together a solution by putting horizontal spacing on every item to shift it all to the right.

Here's an example of the chunk of source that's giving me problems.

```
\hspace{1cm} \textit{Special heading}
\begin{multicols}{2}

  \hspace{1cm}
  Foo
  \newline
  \hspace{1cm}
  Bar
  \newline
  \hspace{1cm}
  Bat
  \newline
  \end{multicols}
```

When this compiles, the header line is indented by a centimeter, as is the first item in the list ("Foo"), however, none of the other items are indented.

I've tried several other spacing commands from the list in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/what-commands-are-there-for-horizontal-spacing#), and they all lead to the same problem.

**Edit:** Here's a full compile-able document, by request. This complies with `pdflatex filename.tex` with TeX Live installed on osx, and shows the error.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{moderncv}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multicol}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{green}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2cm}
\name{Name}{}
\address{Last update: September 22, 2017} %% total hack to get last rev date instead of
                                %% address in here.
\phone[office]{Number (office)}
\email{email}
\homepage{page}
    \begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\lfoot{\thepage}

\section{Here's a normal section}
\cventry
{09/12-Present}
{The thing}
{The other thing}
{That thing}
{}
{\begin{itemize}%
    \item here's a bit of a thing.
    \item and another.
    \end{itemize}}


\section{Stuff}
\subsection{More Stuff}
\cvitem
{2019}
{Stuff.}
\vspace{1mm}
\cvitem
{2017-9}
{Stuff.}

\subsection{Problematic Section}
\hspace{1cm} \textit{Special Header}
\begin{multicols}{2}

  \hspace{1cm}
  Foo
  \newline
  \hspace{1cm}
  Bar
  \newline
  \hspace{1cm}
  Bat
  \newline
  \hspace{1cm}
  Baz
  \newline
  \hspace{1cm}
  One more for good measure
  \newline
\end{multicols}
\vspace{1mm}
\subsection{Another section that works}
\cvitem
{2016-9}
{Stuff.}
\vspace{1mm}
\cvitem
{2016}
{Thingy.}
\end{document}
```

And here's a shot of the problematic output:

[image: problematic output]

as you can see, only the italicized sub-header and the first item are indented, when all the items in the multicolumn list ought to be indented.

Comment: @PaulGowder: Have you tried `\hspace*`?

Comment: ooh, awesome, `\hspace*` does the trick.  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class `moderncv` in current version 2.0.0 has several commands to typeset closer text, for example `\cvlistdoubleitem`, `\cvdoubleitem` or `\cvcolumn`.

Because you gave no information about the real content (`bla` is not really helpful in this case ;-)) I have a little bit to guess. Command `\cvlistdoubleitem` adds an textbullet in front of the added information you seem not to want. So you can define a new command `\mycvlistdoubleitem` like:

```
\newcommand*{\mycvlistdoubleitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{}{\begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemcolumnwidth}#2\end{minipage}%
  \hfill% fill of \separatorcolumnwidth
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}%
    {}%
    {\begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemcolumnwidth}#3\end{minipage}}}}
```

and the usage

```
\mycvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\mycvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5}
```

With the following complete code

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{green}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand*{\mycvlistdoubleitem}[3][.25em]{% <=========================
  \cvitem[#1]{}{\begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemcolumnwidth}#2\end{minipage}%
  \hfill% fill of \separatorcolumnwidth
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}%
    {}%
    {\begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemcolumnwidth}#3\end{minipage}}}}

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2cm}
\name{Joe}{Doe}
\address{Last update: September 22, 2017} %% total hack to get last rev date instead of address in here.
\phone[office]{Number (office)}
\email{email}
\homepage{page}


\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\lfoot{\thepage}

\section{Stuff}
\subsection{More Stuff}
\cvitem{2019}{Stuff.}
\vspace{1mm}
\cvitem{2017-9}{Stuff.}

\subsection{Problematic Section}
\hspace*{1cm} \textit{Special Header}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \hspace*{1cm}
  Foo
  \newline
  \hspace*{1cm}
  Bar
  \newline
  \hspace*{1cm}
  Bat
  \newline
  \hspace*{1cm}
  Baz
  \newline
  \hspace*{1cm}
  One more for good measure
  \newline
\end{multicols}
\vspace{1mm}

\section{Extra 2}
\mycvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4} % <=================================
\mycvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5}
\mycvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\end{document}
```

you get the following result:

[image: resulting cv]

As you can see your solution with corrected command `\hspace*{1cm}` starts in the column reserverd for dates. In my marked section 1 in red circle you see the result of the new command `\mycvlistdoubleitem`, below you can see the result of the original command `\cvlistdoubleitem`, the marked 2 in red circle shows the result of command `\cvdoubleitem` also reaching in the first column for the dates.

I think possibility 1 fits best to the layout of style classic of class `moderncv` in your case ...

Comment: Finally got a chance to try this.  The bullet point version with the built in `\cvlistdoubleitem` works, but with your custom code I'm getting: 

`*\mycvlistdoubleitem{data for col 1.}{data for col 2.} ! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \listdoubleitemcolumnwidth`

Per [this previous SO](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310465/cvdoublecolumn-producing-an-error-while-making-references-using-the-package-mode), I'm upgraded modern cv, but no difference.

Comment: Actually, your reply comment gave me the hint I needed: there was something wrong with the build process. I'm using this as part of a node-based build pipeline with templating and [node-latex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-latex)---but it works fine when I just generated a tex file with my template and used ordinary `pdflatex` to build.  So, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to do with `multicol` or the `moderncv`, it is just that `\\` drops spaces before and after it because normally you don't want them creeping in. And `\hspace{xxx}` is just like an ordinary word space only to a specific width so that gets dropped too. What you want is a `\hspace*{xxx}` if you really want to do that level of explicit formatting.