# \listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth undefined in moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I've been learning `moderncv` to prepare my CV since the beginning of last year, yet I am not quite familiar with the details.

I have included in my resume a section "referees" using the code [suggested by other users](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34881/references-section-in-a-cv). It worked perfectly in the past but it seems some of the code is currently outdated and the code is not functioning. Whenever I compile the code I receive the following message:

```
​! Undefined control sequence. <argument>
   \listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth
```

So I guess the problem lies in the above argument but I am probably wrong.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

%% ModernCV themes
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\nopagenumbers{}

%% Character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%% Adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

%% Personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Resumé title (optional)} 
\address{street and number}{postcode city} 
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890} 
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901} 
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012} 
\email{john@doe.org} 
\homepage{www.johndoe.com} 
\extrainfo{additional information} 
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
\quote{Some quote (optional)}

%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Content
%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{ \textit{Grade} }{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cvitem{title}{ \emph{Title} }
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvdoubleitem{category X}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category Y}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 3}
%% ...

%% A publications list
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications} % a bibtex file containing the list of publications

\section{Referees}
\newcommand{\cvdoublecolumn}[2]{%
  \cvline{}{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}#1\end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}#2\end{minipage}%
 }%
}

\newcommand{\cvreference}[7]{%
\textbf{#1}\newline% Name
\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\addresssymbol~#2\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{#3\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{#4\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{#5\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{\emailsymbol~\texttt{#6}\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}{}{\phonesymbol~#7}}

\cvdoublecolumn{\cvreference{Nicolai Reshetikhin}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {University of California}
    {Berkeley, CA 94720-3840}
    {}
    {reshetik@math.berkeley.edu}
    {510-643-6234}%
    }
    {\cvreference{Mikhail Khovanov}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {Columbia University}
    {990 Broadway}
    {New York, NY 10027}
    {khovanov@columbia.edu}
    {212-854-4186}%
    }


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If I compile the exact code, I get no error and no output.

Comment: Sorry I just made some modifications with the code and I included a photo of the output. It should look more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Well, an quick and dirty solution is to define the missing variable (used in an today outdated version of `moderncv`) new and set an proper value, for example with

```
\newlength{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}%
\setlength{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}{6.5cm}%
```

(Change `6.5cm` to a value you need ...)

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % version ??

%% ModernCV themes
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\nopagenumbers{}

%% Character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%% Adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

%% Personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Resumé title (optional)} 
\address{street and number}{postcode city} 
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890} 
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901} 
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012} 
\email{john@doe.org} 
\homepage{www.johndoe.com} 
\extrainfo{additional information} 
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image}
\quote{Some quote (optional)}

\newlength{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}%
\setlength{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}{6.5cm}%

%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Content
%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{ \textit{Grade} }{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cvitem{title}{ \emph{Title} }
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvdoubleitem{category X}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category Y}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 3}
%% ...

%% A publications list
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications} % a bibtex file containing the list of publications

\section{Referees}
\newcommand{\cvdoublecolumn}[2]{% \cvdoubleitem[spacing]{header1}{text1}{header2}{text2} \cvlistdoubleitem[label]{item1}{item2}
  \cvline{}{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}#1\end{minipage}% \newcounter{cvcolumnscounter}
  \hfill%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}#2\end{minipage}% \newcounter{cvcolumnsautowidthcounter}
 }%
}

\newcommand{\cvreference}[7]{%
\textbf{#1}\newline% Name
\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\addresssymbol~#2\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{#3\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{#4\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{#5\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{\emailsymbol~\texttt{#6}\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}{}{\phonesymbol~#7}}

\cvdoublecolumn{\cvreference{Nicolai Reshetikhin}
  {Department of Mathematics}
  {University of California}
  {Berkeley, CA 94720-3840}
  {}
  {reshetik@math.berkeley.edu}
  {510-643-6234}%
}
{\cvreference{Mikhail Khovanov}
  {Department of Mathematics}
  {Columbia University}
  {990 Broadway}
  {New York, NY 10027}
  {khovanov@columbia.edu}
  {212-854-4186}%
}


\end{document}
```

with the result (with an current version 2.0.0 of `moderncv`)

[image]