# Defining a timeline with fractions of a year exits with error

Tags: moderncv, moderntimeline

Following the example given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54705/moderncv-with-moderntimeline-how-do-i-center-the-label-above-the-timeline), I implemented it myself to use it for my CV. However, I do experience problems, when using fractions of a year for the end of an occupation. This means, that whenever I use

```
\tllabelcventry{2012.667}{2014.667} %
{09/2012--11/2014} %
{Position}{Company}{Location}{} %
{Job Description}
```

it does not work, but when replacing `2014.667` with `2014` for the end, the process exits normally. Otherwise it fails with the error

> `!' Missing = inserted for \ifnum.

```
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, roman]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{grey}
%timeline implementation
\usepackage[firstyear=2005,lastyear=2016]{moderntimeline}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    tl@startyear/.append style={
        xshift=(0.5-\tl@startfraction)*\hintscolumnwidth,
        anchor=base
    }
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lmodern}
%\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{lmss}
% character encoding
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
             % replace by the encoding you are using
\usepackage{multicol}
% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                      % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates

\firstname{firstname}

\familyname{lastname}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}    

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\tllabelcventry{2012.667}{2014} %
{09/2012--11/2014} %
{Position}{Company}{Location}{} %
{Job Description}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the documentation of current `moderntimeline` (`texdoc moderntimeline`). The package has changed since the date, your linked question was asked ... In the documentation on page 3 you will find:

> You can also specify months (which are used only for adjusting the bar
>   length: they are not shown in the labels), separated by a slash from
>   the year

Conclusion: Do not use `year.decimal`, only use `year/month`!

The following code compiles:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{grey}

%timeline implementation
\usepackage[firstyear=2005,lastyear=2016]{moderntimeline}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    tl@startyear/.append style={
        xshift=(0.5-\tl@startfraction)*\hintscolumnwidth,
        anchor=base
    }
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lmodern}
%\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{lmss}
% character encoding
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
             % replace by the encoding you are using
\usepackage{multicol}
% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                      % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates

\firstname{firstname}

\familyname{lastname}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}    


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\tllabelcventry{2012.667}{2014} %
{09/2012--11/2014} %
{Position}{Company}{Location}{} %
{Job Description}

\tllabelcventry{2012/9}{2014/11} % <====================================
{09/2012--11/2014} %
{Position}{Company}{Location}{} %
{Job Description}

%\tllabelcventry{2012.667}{2014.667} % <================== wrong syntax!
%{09/2012--11/2014} %
%{Position}{Company}{Location}{} %
%{Job Description}

\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image: result of mwe]