# Time-line for time intervals

Tags: timeline

I search for a command that do something like this: I can enter two time intervals: the first is the total length of the time-line, and the second is the period to be highlighted. For example the following command:

```
\timeline{1900-2000}{1950}{2000}
```

produce something like this:

[image: timeline-1900-2000-1950-2000]

Another example:

```
\timeline{1900-2000}{1925}{1965}
```

[image: timeline-1900-2000-1925-1965]

---

Optionally I can print the years (for example with the `*` symbol):

```
\timeline{*1900-*2000}{*1945}{1976}
```

[image: timelineyears-d1900-d2000-d1945-1976]

If I want to print all the years, I can enter both the following commands:

```
\timeline{*1900-*2000}{*1950}{*2000}
\timeline[*]{1900-2000}{1950}{2000}
```

[image: timelineyears-d1900-d2000-d1950-d2000]

Another example:

```
\timelineyears[*]{1900-2000}{1925}{1965}
```

[image: timelineyears-1900-2000-1925-1965]

---

If I want I can enter an *inexact year* (for example with the `~` symbol), that produce a colour gradient in the direction of that year. Example:

```
\timelineyears{1900-2000}{1945}{~1976}
```

[image: timelineyears-1900-2000-1945-a1976]

```
\timelineyears{1900-2000}{~1945}{1976}
```

[image: timelineyears-1900-2000-a1945-1976]

```
\timelineyears{1900-2000}{~1945}{~1976}
```

[image: timelineyears-1900-2000-a1945-a1976]

(Perhaps, if I enter an *inexact year* and I print it, it is better to differentiate it in some way respect to the exact years.)

---

I can also set the time interval:

```
\settimeinterval{1900-2000}
```

in this way I have only to specify the range to highlight:

```
\timeline{1912}{1920}
```

The time interval remains the same until the next `\settimeinterval` declaration (but I can overwrite it with the default command `\timeline{a-b}{c}{d}`).

Comment: I saw something like that as implementation in the moderncv class. Maybe you can extend it for your purposes? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29725/putting-a-timeline-for-dates-in-moderncv

Comment: See new code (for typesetting tilde).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The command is structured as follows

```
\Timeline[ <option> ]{ <start>-<end> }{ <startint> }{ <endint> }
```

Adding `*` to the option will print all the years, otherwise, none will be printed. The first argument `<start>-<end>` will set the beginning and the end year respectively. The last two arguments set the interval. Adding `~` before the year will activate the gradient effect.

With the help of David Carlisle the tilde has been fixed. Now it will appear when you add a year that's supposed to be inexact.

### Output (various)

[image]

[image]

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\newcommand\Timeline[4][]{%
    % Some options
    \def\printy{*}
    \def\option{#1}
    % Setting Start-End bar
    \StrBehind{#2}{-}[\endyear]
    \StrBefore{#2}{-}[\startyear]
    % Setting Start-End Interval
    \StrRight{#3}{4}[\startint]
    \StrRight{#4}{4}[\endint]
    % Some calculations
    \pgfmathsetmacro\endy{(\endyear-\startyear)/10}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\fromyear{(\startint-\startyear)/10}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\toyear{(\endint-\startyear)/10}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\midy{(\fromyear+\toyear)/2}
    % Fill interval
    \fill (\fromyear,0) rectangle (\toyear,.2);
    % Fill with gradient if ~ is added
    \IfSubStr{#3}{~}{%
        \fill[right color=black, left color=white] (\fromyear,0) rectangle (\midy,.2);
        \node[anchor=north] at (\fromyear,0) {\string~\phantom{#3}};
        }{}
    \IfSubStr{#4}{~}{%
        \fill[right color=white, left color=black] (\midy,0) rectangle (\toyear,.2);
        \node[anchor=north] at (\toyear,0) {\string~\phantom{#4}};
        }{}
    \draw[white] (\fromyear,0) rectangle (\toyear,.2);
    % Print years
    \ifx\option\printy\relax
    \node[anchor=north] at (0,0) {\startyear};
    \node[anchor=north] at (\endy,0) {\endyear};
    \node[anchor=north] at (\fromyear,0) {#3};
    \node[anchor=north] at (\toyear,0) {#4};
    \fi
    % Print rectangle
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (\endy,.2);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\Timeline[*]{1900-2000}{~1950}{1974}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The chronosys package does this, in color, with its "chronoperiod" function. Although I do not think it will do a gradient.